# Trouble with char variable in C

Tags: c, char

why does this code does not accept the letters I set it to accept? It should accept M, F, m and f, but it doesn't what am I missing? ty

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char sexo;
    sexo='A';
    printf("== Entre com o sexo:\n");
    while(sexo!='M'||sexo!='F'||sexo!='m'||sexo!='f'){
        scanf(" %c ", &sexo);
        if(sexo!='M'||sexo!='F'||sexo!='m'||sexo!='f'){
            printf("Sexo invalido!Precisa ser 'M' ou 'F'.\n");
        }
        else{
            return sexo;
        }
    }
    sexo='A';
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `&&` instead of `||`?? And... `scanf (" %c", &sexo)` will do. No need for the additional trailing `' '` in the format string.

Comment: The reverse of e.g. `sexo == 'M' || sexo == 'F'` is `sexo != 'M' && sexo != 'F'`. I suggest you read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications to your code and added some explanations in the comments.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char sexo = 'A';
    printf("== Entre com o sexo:\n");
    while(1) {  // No need to test everything twice. This loop will go until we hit the return inside it.
        scanf("%c", &sexo); // Removed spaces in the formatting string
        sexo = toupper(sexo); // Will make everything uppercase, making the next test simpler.
        if(sexo!='M' && sexo!='F') { // Changed to && - this is true if it is neither M nor F
            printf("Sexo invalido! Precisa ser 'M' ou 'F'.\n");
        }
        else{
            return sexo; // Return here, otherwise keep going. Unlike the original, this will return only M or F, and never m or f
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** One problem with scanf (apart from the fact that it may be unsafe) is that it is very hard to handle errors and input problems, as the one you have commented on in the comments to this answer. There are different better things that can be done here. One of the simpler ones is to use `fgets`, read the entire line and then use the first character, disregarding the rest (or you can add additional error handling). Something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 20

int main() {
    printf("== Entre com o sexo:\n");
    while(1) {  // No need to test everything twice. This loop will go until we hit the return inside it.
        char buf[MAX];
        fgets(buf, MAX, stdin);
        char sexo = toupper(buf[0]);
        if(sexo!='M' && sexo!='F') {
            printf("Sexo invalido! Precisa ser 'M' ou 'F'.\n");
        }
        else{
            return sexo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey tysm for the reply! I tried and apparenly codeblocks returns me this:
"E:\Codeblocks\Projetos\TESTE.c|7|error: 'true' undeclared (first use in this function)|"

Comment: But, if I replace true with:
"sexo!='M'&&sexo!='F'&&sexo!='m'&&sexo!='f'"
it works flawlessly!!

Comment: And just like in my code, it returns "Sexo invalido! Precisa ser 'M' ou 'F'" twice if i type a char that is different from M or F

Comment: OK. The first was a C++ "bug". You can replace `true` with 1. The multiple messages you are getting are because scanf reads from a stream. For example, if you entered DDDDDF, you will get 4 messages of invalid sex and then the program finishes, returning F. When you enter G, your input stream actually contains two characters (G and \n). The \n is read in the second run, hence you are getting two messages. You can see that by adding `printf("%d\n", sexo);` right after the scanf statement. You should not be using scanf(). Try something else, like gets(). I added edit of my answer to help.